# 届けるなってな meaning

Tags: grammar

I cannot understand the sentence from the grammar point. Could you please explain "届けるなってな" to me?
Why do the Japanese attach なって after the "る" form. What does the particle "な" mean in this context?

Comment: Can you provide the context?

Comment: Without context it isn't clear how to interpret this. It could be the case that the sentence is meant as 「届けるな　って　な」, with 届けるな being the negative imperative.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters noted, context would be most appreciated, but it would seem more than likely that this is a contraction of

届けるなって[言う・言っている]な (= 届けるなと言っているな）

'You are telling me not to deliver it, right?'

demonstrating the (frequent) omission of iu/itte iru after to/tte.

If you provide context, this guess may turn out to be quite wrong however.

Answer (score 0):

If the "な" or "なあ" at the end is often used in the lines of a specific individual, it is just a habit and you can ignore it to read.

> 僕はいつもご飯を食べるんだ(な(あ))。
> そうやってあの子を責めるんだ(な(あ))。

If you value subtle nuances, you can read that the subject of the sentence evaluates things from an objective or introspective standpoint.